# Issue with scipy.io.wavfile.read and scipy.fftpack.fft

Tags: scipy, fft

```
from os.path import dirname, join as pjoin
import scipy.io as sio
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy.fftpack import fft

data_dir = pjoin(dirname(sio.__file__), 'tests', 'data')
wav_fname = pjoin(data_dir, 'test-44100Hz-2ch-32bit-float-be.wav')
print(wav_fname)

def create_FFT(fn,size=1000):
    sample_rate, X = wavfile.read(fn)
    fft_features = abs(fft(X)[:size])
    return(sample_rate, X, fft_features)

for wav_fn in wav_fname :
    samplerate, data, fft_features = create_FFT(wav_fn)
    print(f"number of channels = {data.shape[1]}")
    print("fft features are: {}".format(fft_features))
```

> In the above code, if I don't include fft specific code in the create_FFT function, I could read the file and print the number of channels. However, as soon as I include fft specific code, I get an error **"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C'"**

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It was with the for loop at the bottom.